# Program still wants to take input even if the all pipes are closed

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork, system-calls

I am trying to realize this scenario:

[fork and pipe scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3WmF.png)

where two parallel processes are piped to `tr /a-z/ /A-Z/` and finally `tr /a-z/ /A-Z/` process is connected to stdout.

I've written this program to try to achieve my goal:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<wait.h>

int main()
{
    int dummy;
    int fd[2];
    int i;
    char* lsargs[]  = {"/bin/ls", "-l", NULL};
    char* lsargs2[] = {"cat", "/etc/group", NULL};
    char* lsargs3[] = {"tr", "/a-z/", "/A-Z/", NULL};
    char** am[] = {lsargs, lsargs2, lsargs3};

    pipe(fd);

    for ( i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ )
    {
        pid_t pid = fork();

        if ( pid == 0 )
        {
            if ( i != 2 ) // ls -l & cat
            {
                // 0 -> stdin, 1 -> pipe write end
                close(fd[0]);
                dup2(fd[1], 1);
                close(fd[1]);
                execvp(am[i][0], am[i]);
            }
            else //TR AZ AZ
            {
                // 0 -> pipe read end 1 -> stdout
                close(fd[1]);
                dup2(fd[0],0);
                close(fd[0]);
                execvp(am[i][0], am[i]);
            }
            break;
        }
        else{
            wait(&dummy);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get the correct output but my program doesn't terminate, it still wants to take input. Can you please help me to understand the reason?

Comment: You're waiting after forking the first process. Your loop is too clever, I suggest you'd unroll the loop

Comment: @AnttiHaapala what would you suggest? I know using a loop is meaningless, I used it for a special purpose.

Comment: Instead of using `for` write the code so that it repeats itself; then you can recognize which part can be repeated and why. Now your parent will `wait` for the first child to exit *before* the next child is even forked, execed nor got its pipe running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top level process is not closing the pipe. Since the parent process is really just a coordinator and doesn't actually use the pipe it needs to close both ends once all the last `fork` call has been made. One way to do this is to add the close code into the `else` case. For example:

```
else {

    /* ADDED CODE - close the pipes after last fork */
    if (i == 2) {
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
    }

    wait(&dummy);
}
```

Comment: Code works in the way I want but Antti Haapala's comment in the main post makes me wonder: Do I use wait(&dummy) apporpriately? If not, how can I use it appropriately.

Comment: @ArdaGüney Well it depends on what your desired behaviour is. Your current wait behaviour is correct if you want the `ls` and `cat` output to be sequenced one after the other. If you don't wait after at least the first `fork` then the `ls` and `cat` output is likely to come out interleaved as they will both attempt to concurrently write to the `pipe` and it will thus be indeterminate what the output ordering will be.

Comment: I can't figure out how to leave no zombies behind and also make ls & cat run concurrently. Adding an `if (i != 0)` statement to wait(&dummy) doesn't work.

Comment: To do that just take the `wait` call out of the current `for` loop and then add another `for` loop after the existing one that just calls `wait` 3 times.

Comment: I did take `wait(&dummy)` outside of the loop and called three times. I was excepting an output which `ls -l` and `cat /etc/group` are **shuffled**, but I got an **ordered** output. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: When you do that there is no guarantee of ordering. So you cannot know for sure whether it will be ordered or interleaved. It is timing dependent. For example, say you had a directory with many many files. If the `ls` process gets scheduled first then it is possible that it may get suspended again before the `cat` process executes. In that case the output would be interleaved.